# Unable to set ng-model of <select> in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am new to angularjs/javascript as such and i am faced with the below issue.
I tried setting the ng-model of my select in js but in the html the 'selectedValue' is not shown.

Kindly help!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <select ng-model="selectedName" ng-options="o.name for o in selectNameOptions">
    </select>

    <br/>
    <br/>
    <i>selectedAccount: {{selectedName}}</i>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <i>selectAccountOptions: {{selectNameOptions}}</i>
    <br/>
  </div>

  <script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {

      var name1 = {
        name: "Emil",
        age: 25,
        label: "Emil 25"
      };
      var name2 = {
        name: "Tobias",
        age: 20,
        label: "Tobias 20"
      };
      var name3 = {
        name: "Linus",
        age: 15,
        label: "Linus 15"
      };
      $scope.selectNameOptions = [name1, name2, name3];

      // set emil as intial selection
      $scope.selectedName = {
        name: "Emil",
        age: 25,
        label: "Emil 25"
      };

    });
  </script>

  <p>"Emil" is not selected, eventhough i have indicated the object in js.</p>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that you're assigning a new object to `$scope.selectedName`. Though it matches all the values inside, it still isn't the same object.

Angular matches the objects by their references. So, the quick fix to your problem is to assign `name1` to `$scope.selectedName` instead. See the fix in the below snippet:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {

  var name1 = {
    name: "Emil",
    age: 25,
    label: "Emil 25"
  };
  var name2 = {
    name: "Tobias",
    age: 20,
    label: "Tobias 20"
  };
  var name3 = {
    name: "Linus",
    age: 15,
    label: "Linus 15"
  };

  $scope.selectNameOptions = [name1, name2, name3];

  // set emil as intial selection
  $scope.selectedName = name1;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <select ng-model="selectedName" ng-options="o.name for o in selectNameOptions">
  </select>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <i>selectedAccount: {{selectedName}}</i>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <i>selectAccountOptions: {{selectNameOptions}}</i>
  <br/>
</div>
```

A more sensible fix is to use a unique identifier of the object (for example `name`) as the value of the `select` box.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {

  var name1 = {
    name: "Emil",
    age: 25,
    label: "Emil 25"
  };
  var name2 = {
    name: "Tobias",
    age: 20,
    label: "Tobias 20"
  };
  var name3 = {
    name: "Linus",
    age: 15,
    label: "Linus 15"
  };

  $scope.selectNameOptions = [name1, name2, name3];

  // set emil as intial selection
  $scope.selectedName = 'Emil';
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <select ng-model="selectedName" ng-options="o.name as o.label for o in selectNameOptions">
  </select>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <i>selectedAccount: {{selectedName}}</i>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <i>selectAccountOptions: {{selectNameOptions}}</i>
  <br/>
</div>
```

Please refer to [this link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select#using-select-with-ngoptions-and-setting-a-default-value) to learn more about `ng-options` directive.

Answer (score 0):

What you are actually doing is you are creating a new object with the same value. But they are different object which are in different location. Modify the code like below and set selectedName to the previous object instead of creating a new one.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <select ng-model="selectedName" ng-options="o.name for o in selectNameOptions">
    </select>

    <br/>
    <br/>
    <i>selectedAccount: {{selectedName}}</i>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <i>selectAccountOptions: {{selectNameOptions}}</i>
    <br/>
  </div>

  <script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {

      var name1 = {
        name: "Emil",
        age: 25,
        label: "Emil 25"
      };
      var name2 = {
        name: "Tobias",
        age: 20,
        label: "Tobias 20"
      };
      var name3 = {
        name: "Linus",
        age: 15,
        label: "Linus 15"
      };
      $scope.selectNameOptions = [name1, name2, name3];

      // set emil as intial selection
      $scope.selectedName = name1;

    });
  </script>

  <p>"Emil" is not selected, eventhough i have indicated the object in js.</p>

</body>

</html>
```